# Set initial value in ASP:DropDown

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an *ASP:DropDown*

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="bloodGroupDS"
 DataTextField="BloodGroup" DataValueField="BloodID">
 // This doesn't show 
 <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="-1">
 Select Blood</asp:ListItem>
```

Which is filled by *DataSource*.

How to show a ListItem as *selected* to provide user a message what to select.

Answer (score 1):

Try this at page load:

```
 ddl1.DataSource = // provide your data source here.
 ddl1.DataValueField = "valuefield";
 ddl1.DataTextField = "textfield";
 ddl1.DataBind();
 ddl1.Items.Insert(0, "--Select--");
```

Answer (score 0):

use the following

```
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true"
                DataSourceID="bloodGroupDS" DataTextField="BloodGroup" DataValueField="BloodID">
               <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="0" Text=" Select Blood" />
            </asp:DropDownList>
```

because you are using DataSource so you have to Make AppendDataBoundItems="true"

Comment: This does not work. I accepted the answer that works. Thanks dear...